# Right way to use ENTRYPOINT to enable container start and stop

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having a custom image built using the `Dockerfile`. Apparently a fresh run works fine however when I stop the container and start it again - it doesn't start and remain in the state of **Exit 0**.

The image is composed of apache2 and bunch of php modules for symfony web application.

This is how `Dockerfile` end

```
RUN a2enmod rewrite
CMD service apache2 restart
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
```

I see containers commonly using docker-entrypoint.sh but unsure of what goes in and the role it plays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entrypoint shouldn't have anything to do with your container not restarting. Your problem is most likely elsewhere and you need to look at the logs from the container to debug. The output of `docker diff ...` may also help to see what has changed in the container filesystem.

If an `ENTRYPOINT` isn't defined, docker runs the `CMD` by default. If an `ENTRYPOINT` is defined, anything in `CMD` becomes a cli argument to the entrypoint script. So in your above example, it will start (or restart) the container with `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND`. Anything you append after the container name in the `docker run` command will override the value of `CMD`. And you can override the value of the `ENTRYPOINT` with `docker run --entrypoint ...`.

See [Docker's documentation on the entrypoint option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) for more details.

Comment: Thank you BMitch - i think we are getting closer. My container exits even when I stop the apache2 process inside it. So I think the answer to the container stop start and apache2 service stop start are one and the same ? Any suggestions to what could be going wrong ?

Comment: Containers isolate a process (e.g. `apache2ctl`). When that process dies, so does the container.

Comment: thank you again - so how you think I should modify the image ? Like listening to a different process - what is mess free way to do that ?

Comment: Not really sure I understand what you're trying to do. If the process isn't running, what do you want to do with the container that you need it up?

Comment: The container just serves a php application thru apache. When run from fresh image - it works as long the apache is running; when i stop the container - i am not able to start the container henceforth (coz. apache isn't running) - how do i work around this ?

Comment: As mentioned above, you'll need to debug the reason apache isn't restarting with logs and a diff. You don't work around not starting apache when it's the process that's being run in the container.

Comment: Thank you BMitch - i completely over looked my Dockerfile commands - I had placed RUN service apache2 start as CMD service apache2 start. Changing hte CMD to RUN did the trick.

Comment: `RUN service apache2 start` in a Dockerfile is a noop, it will start the process in the background, and then the container exits at the end of the brief service command, killing the background apache2 process. You should remove this from your Dockerfile completely.